# How to cast object to interface with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I want to cast an object instantiated from the `Activator` to a interface with a generic type.

```cs
public interface IFoo { }

public interface IBar<T> where T : IFoo {
   void Bal(T item);
}

public abstract class Bar<T> : IBar<T>
  where T : IFoo
{ 
  public abstract void Bal(T item);
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{ }
```

Now I have a lot of classes like `Baz`:

```cs
public class Baz : Bar<Foo>
{
  public override void Bal(Foo item);
}
```

I instantiale `Baz` with the activator.

```
var instanceOfBaz = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Baz));
```

Now I want to cast `Baz` back to the base implementation so I can call method `Bal` from the caller.

```cs
public IBar<IFoo> CreateInstanceOfBaz()
{
  var instanceOfBaz = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Baz));

  var castedBaz = (IBar<IFoo>) instanceOfBaz;
  var alsoCastedBaz = instanceOfBaz as IBar<IFoo>;

  return castedBaz;
}
```

But `castedBaz` will throw a `InvalidCastException` and `alsoCastedBaz` is `null`.
So now I can't call the `Bal` method, nor get the object as `IBar<IFoo>`. I need this because I have a List of the `IBar<IFoo>` which I need in another place.

Above code will compile because the relations are valid, but runtime it will fail.

The project is running .NET Framework 4.7.2 and C# 7.

How do I solve my project so I can get the instantiated object as `IBar<IFoo>`? It is not an option to use reflection to call the `Bal` method, because I will still need the object in my list.

Comment: `IBar<T>` is invariant with regard to `T`, so a `Bar<Foo>` is not a `IBar<IFoo>`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay `IBar<T>` is `IFoo` because that is described in the `where` clause?

Comment: As Johnathan said, your interface is invariant. And even if you introduced variance, it would have to be contravariance - you could cast `Bar<IFoo>` to `Bar<Foo>`, but not the other way around. [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

Comment: `Bar<Foo>` is *not* an `IBar<IFoo>`. If it was and the cast worked, `castedBaz.Bal(new SomethingIFooButDefinitelyNotFoo())` could be called on that poor `Bar<Foo>` which isn't expecting to receive anything other than a `Foo`.

Comment: `Bar<Foo>` is an `IBar<Foo>` but not an `IBar<IFoo>`, and you are trying to cast an instance of `Bar<Foo>` to `IBar<IFoo>`.

Comment: `Baz` inherits from `Bar<Foo>` which implements `IBar<Foo>`. If it were possible to cast to `IBar<IFoo>` then someone could do that and call `castedBaz.Bal(valueWhichIsIFooButNotFoo)` which is going to cause problems. This is why you can't cast this way round even with covariance, you need contravariance which doesn't help to cast `Bar<Foo>` to `IBar<IFoo>`, only the other way round